How to loop through child nodes in xslt, requesting specific output depending on node type
(XSLT 1.0)
I have an xml input like this :
<doc>
    <article>
        <text>
            <p>
                paragraph 1
            </p>
            <p>
                paragraph 2
            </p>
            <inter>
                inter 1
            </inter>
            <p>
                paragraph 3
            </p>
            <p>
                paragraph 4
            </p>
            <inter>
                inter 2
            </inter>
            <p>
                paragraph 5
            </p>
        </text>
    </article>
</doc>

I would need an output like this :
<doc>
    <article>
        <text>
            [TEXT]
            paragraph 1
            paragraph 2
            [INTER]
            inter 1
            paragraph 3
            paragraph 4
            [INTER]
            inter 2
            paragraph 5
        </text>
    </article>
</doc>

So I tried this xsl code :
<xsl:template match="/doc">
<doc>
    <article>
        <text>
            <xsl:text>[TEXT]&#xa;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="article/text">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="p">
                        <xsl:value-of select="p"/>
                        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="intertitre">
                            <xsl:text>[INTER]&#xa;</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="intertitre"/>
                            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </text>
    </article>
</doc>
</xsl:template>

Not working… It seems the script just stops after the first "p" child node so I just get this output :
<doc>
    <article>
        <text>
            [TEXT]
            paragraph 1
        </text>
    </article>
</doc>

What would you suggest ? The "choose… when" statement seemed OK to do the job, but it may not be, or I just missed something… (I'm quite new to xslt…)

You don't really "loop through" XML but more match on a template then have other templates to match what is inside that original template context.

The problem with your attempt is that you do <xsl:for-each select="article/texte"> but there is only one texte (actually none, since it is text, but let's say it's a typo). It should be <xsl:for-each select="article/text/p | article/text/inter">.  Then you would need to test for self::p or self::inter. But this is awkward; separate templates are a better approach here.

P.S. In all your questions regarding XSLT, please state which version of XSLT your processor supports (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153).

michael.hor257k you're right, as for the "texte" that was a typo, I edited my post ; I'll also state the XSLT version.

Is your question not answered? http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

I would use templates:
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="article/text">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text>[TEXT]</xsl:text>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="text/p">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="text/inter">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('[INTER]', .)"/>
  </xsl:template>

Exact indentation/whitespace handling might need adjusting in any case

That's really interesting I shall try this in the real context of my real doc, as michael.hor257k says my first approach is a bit awkward… This one seems to be much better indeed.

This is exactly what template rules are designed for and this is the way any experienced XSLT developer would tackle this problem.

This is what your attempt should look like:
XSLT 1.0
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/doc">
    <doc>
        <article>
            <text>
                <xsl:text>[TEXT]&#xa;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:for-each select="article/text/p | article/text/inter">
                    <xsl:if test="self::inter">[INTER]&#xa;</xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </text>
        </article>
    </doc>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>


That is working perfectly, exactly what I was looking for, thx a lot !
